# Does not stop recording in speech recognition python

Tags: python

I was trying the example code for the first time

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer(language = "en-US"  )
r.pause_threshold = 0.6 
with sr.Microphone() as source:    
    audio = r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    print "Speak Now"
    audio = r.listen(source, timeout=1)                   # listen for the first phrase and extract it into audio data

try:
    print("You said " + r.recognize(audio))    # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
except LookupError:                            # speech is unintelligible
    print("Could not understand audio")
except IndexError:
    print("No internet")
except KeyError:
    print("quota maxed out")
```

But i am getting this

```
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
ALSA lib dlmisc.c:252:(snd1_dlobj_cache_get) Cannot open shared library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_equal.so
ALSA lib dlmisc.c:252:(snd1_dlobj_cache_get) Cannot open shared library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_equal.so
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Speak now
```

and it is then struck there only

What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your input isn't muted.
Second, you may need JACK.

```
sudo apt-get install jackd
```

Or... your mic may not be detecting sound via Alsa and one of the various audio frameworks [GStreamer, PulseAudio, Phonon, OSS, etc]. You'll need to see which combination you're using. Mine was Alsa/PulseAudio/JACK. You didn't mention your distro, so yours may be different. You can then adjust your input port/s which should solve the issue.

After having the same issue and ensuring my input wasn't muted, I downloaded the Pulse Audio volume control:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

What you want to be able to do is set the **input device ports**. Again, depending on your distro and hardware, this may vary from: Internal/external mics, analog/digital options or OSS. Those are some examples of what was in my Input Device Options.
The mic then detected my voice. I received the same exact err messages as you, but the program output was what was expected.

If you read this:
[Speech Recognition 2.0.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/)
You'll see your same code snippet and how to keep those warnings from displaying. The article will also explain everything you'll need to have installed. Such as JACK [jackd].

This article helped me to narrow down the problem:
[How it works: Linux audio explained](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/how-it-works-linux-audio-explained)
It also helped me not to dare attempt fixing this issue from the terminal.

Hope this helps you or others. Good luck.